# How to do meditation if I've got negative thoughts?

Tags: practice, meditation

When ever I try to concentrate in either my breath or a word I am not able to concentrate. Please give me some solution to it.

If I do concentration by ignoring those thoughts than after I open my eyes I don't feel good. So what should I do?

Comment: Related - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16009/auditory-sense-detachment/16013#16013

Comment: my disturbances are not environment factors like noise or anything. my disturbances are my own thoughts and questions which i can't get answer right now.

Comment: Please try asking in Buddhism forum. In general, the idea is to observe the negative thought without  acting on it

Comment: I came to know from a Swamiji of Ramakrishna math that at the beginning ( for few days to months) thoughts are bound to come in your mind and don't try to restrict them but let them come. They come and go, just don't follow the thought. Just calm your mind and enjoy the calmness. Better to find a guru and follow his path.

Comment: personal questions are not allowed on this forum. Change the wording of your question or it will be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`When ever i try to concentrate in either my breath or a word i am not able to concentrate. Please give me some solution to it.`**

Yes , the solution of your above problem is given in various Hinduism scriptures like **Shreemad Bhagvat Gita  , Patanjali YOG-SUTRAS , Aparokshanubhuti** ( by adi Shankaracharya ) etc.

This problem is discussed and possible solutions are also given in below shlokas by various texts.

---

Here is what Shree Adi Shankaracharya Says in his book called [**Aparokshanubhuti**](https://archive.org/stream/Works_of_Sankaracharya_with_Hindi_Translation/AparokshanubhutiWithDipikaHindiTika-RamswarupDvivedi1908khemraj#page/n13/mode/2up)    where he describes a method that seekers can follow to directly experience the essential truth of one's one nature.

> समाधौ क्रियमाणे तु विघ्नान्यायान्ति वै बलात । 
>   अनुसन्धानराहित्यमालस्यं भोगलालसम ।।127।। 
>  लयस्तमश्च विक्षेपो
>   रसास्वाद्श्च शून्यता । 
>  एवं यद्विघ्नबाहुल्यम त्याजं ब्रह्मविदा शनै
>   ।।128।।
>
> While practicing Samadhi there appear unavoidably many obstacles, such
>   as lack of inquiry, idleness, desire for sense-pleasure, sleep,
>   dullness, distraction, tasting of joy, and the sense of blankness. One
>   desiring the knowledge of Brahman should slowly get rid of such
>   innumerable obstacles.
>
> ---
>
> यत्र यत्र मनो याति ब्रह्मण स्तत्र दर्शनात।
>   मनसो धारणं चैव धारणा
>   सा परा मता॥१२२॥
>
> Yatra Yatea Mano Yaati Brahman StaStra Darshanat 
>  Manaso Dharanam
>   Chaiva Dharana Sa Para Mata
>
> Meaning - **A supreme condition (Dharana) is that , in which one
>   realises that , which ever place his mind goes , that place is
>   Brahman.**

Here what Shree Adi Shakarcharya is saying is let your mind go anywhere ,onto anything (good or bad or on materialistic pleasure's) , one should realise that thing as a Brahman, that is Best Dharana.

---

Here is what **Patanjali** advices us on your enquiry in his [**YOG –SUTRAS**](http://www.swamij.com/pdf/yogasutrasinterpretive.pdf)   in the first chapter - Stabilizing and clearing the mind (1.33-1.39)

> मैत्रीकरुणामुदितोपेक्षणां सुखदु:खपुण्यापुण्यविषयाणां भावनात
>   श्र्चित्तप्रसादनम् ||33||
>
> maitreekarunamuditopekshanan sukhaduhkhapunyapunyavishayanan
>   bhavanatashchittaprasadanam
>
> Friendship, mercy, gladness, indifference, being thought of in regard
>   to subjects, happy, unhappy, good and evil respectively, pacify the
>   Chitta.
>
> **1.33** In relationships, the mind becomes purified by cultivating feelings of friendliness towards those who are happy, compassion for
>   those who are suffering, goodwill towards those who are virtuous, and
>   indifference or neutrality towards those we perceive as wicked or
>   evil. (maitri karuna mudita upekshanam sukha duhka punya apunya
>   vishayanam bhavanatah chitta prasadanam) • maitri = friendliness,
>   pleasantness,
>
> ---
>
> प्रच्छर्दनविधारणाभ्याम वा प्राणस्य || 34||
>
> prachchhardanavidharanabhyan va prannasya
>
> **1.34** The mind is also calmed by regulating the breath, particularly attending to exhalation and the natural stilling of
>   breath that comes from such practice. (prachchhardana vidharanabhyam
>   va pranayama)

Here Patanjali is advicing us to calm our mind by improving  and **cultivating good  feelings.**
Then with pacified mind no negative thoughts will come in mind while practicing meditation.
He is also advising us to control negative thoughts coming in mind by **Breathing exercise (Pranayama)**

---

In Shreemad Bhagvad gita Lord Shree Krishna tells this - :

> यतो यतो निश्चरति मनश्चञ्चलमस्थिरम्।
>  ततस्ततो नियम्यैतदात्मन्येव वशं
>   नयेत्।।6.26।।
>
> yato yato niścalati 
>  manaś cañcalam asthiram
>  tatas tato
>   niyamyaitad
>  ātmany eva vaśaṁ nayet
>
> From wherever the mind wanders due to its ﬂickering and unsteady
>   nature, one must certainly withdraw it and bring it back under the
>   control of the Self. [**BG 6.26**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/6/26)
>
> ---
>
> शनैः शनैरुपरमेद् बुद्ध्या धृतिगृहीतया।
>  आत्मसंस्थं मनः कृत्वा न
>   किञ्चिदपि चिन्तयेत्।।6.25।।
>
> śanaiḥ śanair uparamed
>  buddhyā dhṛti-gṛhītayā
>  ātma-saṁsthaṁ
>   manaḥ kṛtvā
>  na kiñcid api cintayet
>
> Gradually, step by step, one should become situated in trance by means
>   of intelligence sustained by full conviction, and thus the mind should
>   be ﬁxed on the Self alone and should think of nothing else.[**BG
>   6.25**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/6/25)

Conclusion - So from above shlokas its clear that can avoid negative thoughts coming in mind during meditation etc. By

- Cultivating good thoughts in mind about others even about bad or evil people.
- By practicing  Breathing exercise OR Pranayama (प्राणायाम).
- Gradually detaching mind from  Material things or  samsara .

Comment: Very nice and iterative answer!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue.The solution that I adopted was my friendship with dese thoughts.Do not try to curb them.More you curb them the more they will rise.Whenever you get such thoughts be watchful.Be aware that you got them.Sit with them.Let them occupy your mind.After a while you would discover the intensity of such thoughts have become less.If you keep on practicing then there would a point that these thoughts would get tired.At this point you may not even bother about them.Also try to know the source of these thoughts.For instance why did you get this thought?Who is responsible for it?What would you have done to neglect it? and so on.
Happy meditation!

Comment: Welcome to SE community. Please try to give a little more elaborate answers and try to include some references from scriptures etc.

Comment: Personal experiences are [not considered as sources](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266/is-personal-experience-a-source). Please add something which support your claims. Adding sources is mandatory on our site.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing is you stop feeding them by worrying or fearing about them. The more you think the more strength they get. Its common for every aspirant so it is natural, you need not worry much about it. Engage your mind in swadhyaya and satsanga whenever you get free time. Give positive suggestions/affirmations whenever you sit for your practice.

> Watch your mind always very carefully. Be vigilant. Be on the alert.
>   Do not allow waves of irritability, jealousy, anger, hatred and lust
>   to rise from the mind. These dark waves are enemies of meditation,
>   peace and wisdom. Suppress them immediately by entertaining sublime
>   and divine thoughts. Evil thoughts that have arisen may be destroyed
>   by originating good thoughts and maintaining them by repeating any
>   Mantra or the name of the Lord, by thinking on any form of the Lord,
>   by practice of Pranayama, by singing the name of the Lord, by doing
>   good action and thinking of the misery that arises from evil thoughts.
>   When you attain the state of purity, no evil thoughts will arise in
>   your mind. Just as it is easy to check the intruder or enemy at the
>   gate, so also it is easy to overcome an evil thought as soon as it
>   arises. Nip it in the bud. Do not allow it to strike deep root.
>
> In the beginning of your practice of thought-control, you will
>   experience great difficulty. You will have to wage war with them. They
>   will try their level best for their own existence. They will say, "we
>   have every right to remain in this palace of mind. We have a sole
>   monopoly from time immemorial to occupy this area. Why should we
>   vacate our dominion now? We will fight for our birthright till the
>   end." They will pounce upon you with great ferocity. When you sit for
>   meditation only, all sorts of evil thoughts will crop up. As you
>   attempt to suppress, they want to attack you with redoubled force and
>   vigour. But positive always overcomes the negative. Just as darkness
>   cannot stand before the sun, just as the leopard cannot stand before
>   the lion, so also all these dark, negative thoughts, these invisible
>   intruders, enemies of peace, cannot stand before the sublime thoughts.
>   They must die by themselves.
>
> When you are very busy in your daily work, you may not harbour any
>   impure thoughts; but when you take rest and leave the mind blank, the
>   impure thoughts will try to enter insidiously. You must be careful
>   when the mind is relaxed.
>   [Source](http://sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=1718)